# Can't create a class using headers

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm learning C++ from the book Primer C++.
Differently from what I used to do in Java, I learnt that is good practice defining classes and classes' methods' prototypes in a header file.
So I did it, following step by step the book, implementing the methods and constructors in a .cpp file.

The result is an endless amount of error reports.

**Student.h**

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H_
#define STUDENT_H_
class Student{
    private:
        string firstname;
        string lastname;
        double gpa;
    public:
        Student();
        Student(string fname,string lname, double aGpa);
        ~Student();
        void Show();
        double getGpa();
};
#endif
```

*On compile returns the following errors:*

- unknown name type "class"
- expected { etc etc after the Student
  attribute (of course, since it can't understand it's a class)

I also tried to include the cstring and the string library (both couldn't be found by the compiler, I suppose because it's something only a .cpp file can access) ending with using the  library, but that didn't change a thing.

**Student.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "student.h"

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;


Student::Student(){
    cout << "Default constructor called\n";
    cout << "No info regarding the student. Object not initialized";
}
Student::Student(string fname,string lname, double aGpa){
    this->firstname=fname;
    this->lastname=lname;
    this->gpa=aGpa;
}
void Student::Show(){
    cout << lastname <<", " << firstname <<"\nGPA: " << gpa << endl;
}
double Student::getGpa(){
    return this->gpa;
}
Student::~Student(){
    cout<< "Object student has been destroyed";
}
```

*On compile returns the following errors*

- string (in student.h) does not name a type (even if I include string.h)
- in Student.h, expected ')' before fname (in the constructor declaration)
- in Student.cpp, expected constructor before '(' token (in the constructor declaration)
- In function Show(), lastname and firstname etc are not declared in this scope (but GPA is apparently)

Comment: student.h you need to use name of file: Student.h

Comment: I realize it's a bit early for you in your C++ learning, but it's time to learn about namespaces. You need to qualify `string`  with its namespace (`std::string`). Typically this is avoided in intro classes by having a `using namespace std;` in the header, which is a really bad practice. You got part of the way with `using std::cout` in the impl file. Also, you're missing an include for `<string>`, which is not the same as `cstring`.

Comment: Also, instead of includeing <cstring>, try including <string>. The latter deals with c++ style strings, where the first deals with c-style strings, which are basically arrays of characters

Comment: I used the name "Student.h" in my comments to make it somewhat easier to read, but the files are correctly named "student.h" and "student.cpp" in my directory (otherwise when I compile student.cpp I would receive an error saying that student.h doesn't even exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about your compiler errors, but your header file is missing something to use the `std::string`:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
```

are your sure you use a c++ compiler and not a c compiler?

Comment: I am using Dev C++ but for some reasons, using the #include string and the using std lines in the header file simply doesn't work

Comment: It should work, here "Compilation successful" with `using namespace std`: http://cpp.sh/6yr7o

Comment: @kn0bbulo: When you say "simply doesn't work", what is the error message? Also, everytime you want to say "it doesn't work", instead provide the error message.

Comment: @AndyG you're right sorry. I meant that if I use #include string, the compiler says  that there is "no such file or directory". It's like when using a header file, it's automatically compiled in C and not C++

Comment: If you get an error on `#include <string>`, then you may have an installation problem. If you move all your code into the header file it works just fine, though?

Comment: @AndyG yes it does. Now I tried to modify the header file so that it uses a char array instead strings (which is something I hate, I prefer to work with strings) and the program runs just fine (if I compile the header I still get an error though, since "class" is a not-recognized type)

Comment: Problem solved. Looks like I simply had to put "using std::string" before including the student.h file. It's probably what @xander wanted me to see, but unfortunately the link he's given doesn't work.

Comment: good, the link works fine for me!? anyway my answer was meant to be included inside your header file (student.h) before your line `class Student{`. I didn't want to repeat your code, but next time I'll be more clear about it. :)